# Taking a snapshot using the webcam in a console application

Tags: vb.net, webcam, snapshot

I found this awesome class for viewing the webcam [Vb-Net-WebCam-Class](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?344471-Vb-Net-WebCam-Class-%28ICam%29) but it requires pictureboxes, which you can't use in a console application.

So I'm just wondering if there's any way to take a snapshot using the webcam in a console application using that class?

I'm using Visual Basic .NET (2010)

---

Here's the code for taking a snapshot using a forms application if anyone's interested:

```
Private Sub Snap()
    Dim Webcam As iCam = New iCam
    Webcam.initCam(PictureBox1.Handle.ToInt32)
    Application.DoEvents()
    If Webcam.isRunning Then
        PictureBox2.Image = Webcam.copyFrame(PictureBox1, New RectangleF(0, 0, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height))
    End If
    Webcam.closeCam()
    Webcam = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could still use the class to get the job done, but you'd probably need to edit it. You could first try passing `Nothing` as the picturebox parameter, but this would only work if the class is checking if the picturebox IsNot Nothing.

If that is not the case, it still wouldn't be too difficult to edit. It looks like the webcam updates the "source picturebox" with the image, and the `copyFrame` function retrieves the image from that picturebox after it has an image assigned. Instead of using this picturebox, you could save the picturebox from the webcam to a file and modify the `copyFrame` function to retrieve the image it will return from that image path, instead of from the picturebox.